# How can I get and modify response.body in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, express

I am using express and write this code in a middleware. I need to proxy a request to another newUrl and have to get the body of the response from newUrl. But I don't know how to get it in this way. Can anybody tell me how to get the res.body?

```
var stream = req.pipe(request(newUrl)).pipe(res);
stream.on('finish', function() {
    // how can I get res.body from the newUrl?

    next();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy way on how to make proxy request using streams.

```
'use strict';

const
    stream = require('stream'),
    util = require('util'),
    http = require('http');

let Transform = stream.Transform;

// make Trasform stream
function MyProxyStream(options) {
  if (!(this instanceof MyProxyStream)) {
    return new MyProxyStream(options);
  }
  // set proxy url
  this.proxyUrl = 'http://go-to-proxy'
  Transform.call(this, options);
}
util.inherits(MyProxyStream, Transform);


// Transform stuff here
MyProxyStream.prototype._transform = function (chunk, enc, cb) {
    // send proxy request somethere -> get data
    // chunk is string cast to Object with JSON.parse(chunk)
    // request.post(this.proxyUrl, chunk)
    let data = "my proxy data";
    this.push(data);
  return cb();
};

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    let transformer = new MyProxyStream({objectMode: true});
  req.setEncoding('utf8');
  req.pipe(transformer).pipe(res);
});

server.listen(1337);
```

Hope this helps.